# Is there any way I can make 200 similar divs with different files (page0.svg, page1.svg..., page200.svg)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```
<div class="mySlides">
  <img src="1173/page0.svg" style="width:50%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <img src="1173/page1.svg" style="width:50%">
</div>
```

So I need to make about 200 div codes like the above with different .svg files, and the only thing that changes in the file name is the number. I'm trying to create a digital book, and I have all the pages in .svg format.

Comment: I would use a loop to create a fragment  [document.createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there are lots of different ways to do this. As suggested above you can use a fragment to give you better performance than adding 200 divs to the DOM sequentially.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(i=0;i<200;i++){
    var new_div = document.createElement("div");
    new_div.classList.add("mySlides");
    new_div.innerHTML += '<img src="1173/page'+i+'.svg" style="width:50%">';
    fragment.appendChild(new_div);
}

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

See it running here: https://codepen.io/67hours/pen/gBMygW

Comment: nice approach - why wouldn't you want to take the same approach of using `document.createElement` with the `img` tag? Consistency would help readability if nothing else :)

Comment: @JoshE yes very true, I guess I was being lazy! Please edit it in :)

Answer (score 1):

In pure JS, you could write something like this. Using `document.createElement` and then appending the new elements to the parent container is a far superior approach to manipulating the DOM than that of HTML string manipulation/concatenation with elements' `innerHTML` attributes.

Substitute the hard-coded loop limit for a variable representing the actual number (assumes as well you have a `0.svg`):

```
var IMAGE_COUNT = 200;
for (var i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++) {
    var frag = document.createElement("div");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    frag.classList.add('mySlides');
    frag.style = "width:50%;";
    img.src = '1173/page/' + i + '.svg';

    frag.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(frag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop upto 200 and generate html dynamcally and append that to parent div

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var html = "";
   for(var i=0;i<=200; i++)
   {
    html += "<div class='mySlides'><img src='1173/page"+i+".svg' style='width:50%'></div>";
    }
    conatiner.innerHTML = html;
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: manually generating and concatenating an HTML string is wasting the built-in DOM doc and fragment manipulation functionality (among other things) -- e.g., `document.createDocumentFragment`, as suggested by @enxaneta.

Comment: I know but this is also a way to do that, there is nothing wrong with that

Comment: I understand why you're saying that, and I respectfully disagree. Someone trying to learn HTML/JS who comes across this might be led to think that this is a recommended approach, which it is not. Why? Because it a) is brittle and will not adapt well to change, b) is tough to maintain due to numerous underlying assumptions, c) is difficult to expand/enrich without effort, and d) couples together behavior and presentation concerns quite closely (what happens when your designer wants to make a change to the layout?). HTH